# Why wasn't Neo possessed by an Agent in the first movie?

Tags: the-matrix

If an Agent can possess anyone still connected to the Matrix, and, as we can see, they sense when someone is seen something weird (like the drunk beggar in the first movie), why didn't they possess Neo when he was in the car with Switch Apoc and Trinity?

I believe that's what Trinity meant when she said the gun was for *their* protection from *him*

> **Neo:** what is this? (*talking about the gun pointed to him*)
>   **Trinity:** It is necessary, for our protection.
>   **Neo:** From what?
>   **Trinity:** From you!

Comment: I thought that comment was more about the fact that he was still an unknown quantity at that point. They had no idea if he could truly be trusted, or if he would have a mental breakdown, or whatever.

Comment: My [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71186/31936) to "What was the point of the bug?" explains this.